# Rich List Pagination in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint list with data that I need to display page by page. The must requirement is ability to jump through pages and show total page count (i.e. 1,2,3 ... 15). Does SharePoint allow to do that?

By far I tried:
CAML : seems not to be possible, as the CAML query requires element from the previous page to display the next one.

REST : using /_vti_bin/listdata.svc and LINQ query:

```
//VS2010 creates classes for all list items when adding reference to listdata.svc
RootDataContext context = new RootDataContext(new Uri(Utils.ListServiceUrl)); 
context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

//this works like a charm, I am able to filter items by category and page them 
//(category is a single lookup)
var query = (DataServiceQuery<NewsItemsItem>)context.NewsItems.
            Where(i => i.CategoryId == 2).
            Skip(3).
            Take(2);

//however, if I need more advanced filtering (Tags is multilookup) I fail 
//(the code below won't work as this approach does not allow to make aggregation 
//queries inside other query)
var query = (DataServiceQuery<NewsItemsItem>)context.NewsItems.
            Where(i => i.Tags.Where(t => t.Id == 3).Count() > 0).
            Skip(3).
            Take(2);
```

I would be grateful if you could give me any advise.

Comment: Decided to get rid of multilookup column in my list and put a simple string column instead (i.e. #1#4#6). Now I can use REST approach here.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798478.aspx
Skip with linq to sharepoint can not help you. Because sharepoint doesn`t have some tool to "skip N values".

Check this articles. They will be very usefull if you have order by column and want to paginate this list with this order by in caml.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbadki/archive/2008/10/08/caml-query-execution-using-pagination-for-custom-columns.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/colbyafrica/archive/2009/02/19/learning-sharepoint-part-vi-list-pagination.aspx

Anyway list pagination in sharepoint is quiet horrible (i think not only for me). Because i can only paginate like "previous - next" not "1 2 3 4 5 .... " pages

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided to use Linq to SharePoint anyway, as there is no acceptable way to organize "1 2 3"-style control using CAML. One problem I had is querying on multi-lookup column, you cannot do that by neither way, so I ended up changing the list structure.